# Универсальный редактор справочников

Tags: c#, ado.net, база-данных

Очередная моя заморочка готовых "велосипедов", вроде как не нашёл, поэтому взялся делать сам что-то вроде универсального редактора таблиц в БД. Имеются, соответственно, таблицы. К ним добавил общую, для редактирования. Внёс в неё: названия справочников, строки селекта, инсерта, апдейта, и делейта. Также внёс: название таблиц в БД, название идентифицирующего столбца каждой таблицы. Посчитал, что эти данные мне нужны будут в дальнейшем. На данный момент смог сделать только вывод этих таблиц следующим кодом:

```
 protected void lb_catalogs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string cmdsel = dv_editcatalog.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text;
            string cmdupd = dv_editcatalog.Rows[3].Cells[1].Text;
            string cmdins = dv_editcatalog.Rows[4].Cells[1].Text;
            string cmddel = dv_editcatalog.Rows[5].Cells[1].Text;

            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conn);
            SqlCommand cmd_SQL = new SqlCommand(cmdsel, sqlcon);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdsel, sqlcon);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText = cmdsel;
            //da.UpdateCommand.CommandText = cmdupd;
            //da.InsertCommand.CommandText = cmdins;
            //da.DeleteCommand.CommandText = cmddel;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "TableAny");

            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["TableAny"];

            this.DataBind();
     }
```

На странице создал скрытый `detailsview`, для получения всех данных о выбранном справочнике. Сначала был программный запрос к БД, но это было громоздко, поэтому решил упростить пока так. Данные загружаются в гридвайв, генерятся кнопки sel, upd, del. Из них работает только sel. Помогите осуществить задуманное. Не знаю как привязать оставшиеся команды к gridview'у. Кроме команды select больше ничего не присваивается пишет:

> "Ссылка на объект не указывает на
> экземпляр объекта."

Может выбрал неверное направление? Может лучше кодом управлять датасоурсом? Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Пробовали в свойствах GridView искать обработчики событий? Там, по идее, должны быть на обновление и удаление...

Comment: Нашёл решение, правда за счёт среды разработки, там GridView берёт всё из Datasuorce, который в свою очередь контролируется посредством AJAX. Сейчас ниже дам ссылки, по которым всё получилось, красиво и быстро, жаль времени нету самому разработать. Может быть когда ни будь в будущем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В VS можно создать веб-сайт сущностей динамических данных, который весьма облегчил реализацию, задуманную мною. Единственное с чем необходимо ещё подразобраться, это с запросами, чтобы задать нормальные названия столбцов. Вот посмотрите:

Оглавление всех возможностей: [Использование платформы динамических данных](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc488545(v=VS.90).aspx)

Непосредственно само создание:[Создание нового веб-узла](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc488469(v=vs.90).aspx)

Осталось теперь подстроить веб-узел под мой проект и оформление и займусь логами.

Comment: Блиииин, веб-сайт сущностей это ASP.NET MVC... А у меня обычное веб-приложение. Что-же делать...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать XAF (eXpress Application Framework), Embarcadero или RP Studio.